# Testing Assumption of Linearity for Multinominal Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, assumptions

I have a nominal DV (0 through 3). IVs are all continuous. I'm trying to test the linearity assumption, however I can't run the logistic regression function in SPSS with the LN IV variables because of the DV being more than 2 values. Can someone explain to me how I need to test the assumption in SPSS?

Comment: I don't think you can use logistic regression on a DV with 4 responses, as logistic regression is typically only used for binary responses (0 or 1).

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You might want to start by using a software implementation of a *multinomial* logistic regression. It is not obvious that the SPSS function can handle a multinomial likelihood.

Comment: Did you try Analyze...Regression...Multinomial logistic?

Comment: Be sure your variables are appropriately formatted on the variable view page as well aka nominal variables are nominal, continuous variables are scale, etc. Try also this link for procedure steps - https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/multinomial-logistic-regression-using-spss-statistics.php

Comment: Yes, I'm running as a multinomial log reg. I'm not sure how to test assumption 5 (Assumption #5: There needs to be a linear relationship between any continuous independent variables and the logit transformation of the dependent variable.) from https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/multinomial-logistic-regression-using-spss-statistics.php

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the linearity assumption for multinomial logistic model visually by plotting the residuals separately for each dependent variable category against the predicted probabilities, and by plotting the residuals (again separately for each dependent variable category) against each of your continuous predictors, and look for any patterns in these plots (no pattern = good). I'm not sure how to do this in practice in SPSS unfortunately, but I think [this article](https://www.scalestatistics.com/multinomial-logistic-regression.html) may help.

Comment: I'll definitely try this and report back. Thanks!!

Comment: This link was super helpful and helped me test the assumptions of the multinomial logistic regression. It's a tedious process, but important to do. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hey, I'm really glad it helped - I personally have little experience of multinomial models, but I remembered this is what I was taught back in the day!